# Illustrator - Duplicating text across several artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm creating canvas' of multiple sizes and shapes that have blocks of text that are the same. Is there a way to have edit the text in one instance and have that same text duplicated across all over canvas'?

Comment: Are you asking how to duplicate text on the same spot in all artboards or changing the same text in all artboards at once?

Comment: I'm referring to changing the same text across all artboards at once, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Symbols

Set your text once, then drag the text box to the **Symbols Panel**. You can then place as many instances of the Symbol on different artboards as you want merely copy the original symbol instance (text block). You can even transform (scale, rotate, skew) the symbol instances independently if necessary.

Then if you need to edit the text later, **double-click the Symbol** in the Symbols Panel. Once you edit the text there, all instances will update.

This is about as close as you are going to get to dynamic copies.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is just a matter of duplication, you can simply use the transform effect. In fact, even if the text looks different, you can still keep adding additional fills on a single text, and then use extra effects on those fills to make different-styled text.

[image]